# Is google cloud platform removed some option in Google Cloud SSL/HTTPS Load Balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-load-balancer

Can anyone help me that I am using load balancer in google cloud platform but here I am not able to properly install ssl. Only certificate chain and private key box is showing not public key box. Why it is happening ? Is I have missed something or glitch from google side ?

```
**public key => But where to upload this ??
certificate chain => available
private key => available**
```

[image]

Which one is certificate chain in these that google is asking ?

[image]

And when checking it is showing grade B due to incomplete chain

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you want to achieve. You are using [Google-managed certificate](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs) or [self-managed certificate](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs)? Did you followed docs above?

Comment: I want to solve the issue of ssl when checking speed check of my website then when I checked my ssl it is showing the server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B. So why it is showing certificate chain is incomplete that is my issue.

Comment: Which certificate are you using? Google or your own? Where you are checking this security grade?

Comment: @PjoterS I am using godaddy certificates my own. I am checking on ssllabs.com

Comment: To sum up, you have created SSL certificate via godaddy, then you have followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs) (skipping step 1). So when you have a certificate window to upload your certificate, in `Certificate` you have `The certificate must be in PEM format and include the correct certificate trust chain. The certificate chain must be no greater than 5 certs long.` Could you verify if certs created via godaddy are correct?

Comment: I have solved my problem by `merging certificate chain with my certificate` and that's it. But this thing google have to mention when asking upload public certificate, certificate chain and private key. They have to mention this merge certificate chain and certificate and then private key.

Comment: Kartik Verma please post your solution as an answer. It might help other users with similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected in the comment section, the issue was with a self-managed certificate (Trust Chain).

When creating a Certificate in GCP you can use [Google-Managed](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs?hl=en) and [Self-Managed](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs?hl=en) certificates.

In this setup OP used `GoDaddy Certificate` and validated it on [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). One of the issues was

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.

More details can be found in this article - [How Certificate Chains Work](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO16297.html)

> A certificate chain is an ordered list of certificates, containing an SSL/TLS Certificate and Certificate Authority (CA) Certificates, that enable the receiver to verify that the sender and all CA's are trustworthy.

In [Using self-managed SSL certificates - Step 2: Create a self-managed SSL certificate resource](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs#createresource) guide you can find information that chain certificate needs to be verified by the user:

> Paste in your certificate or click Upload to navigate to your certificate file.
> You can choose to include the CA certificate chain in the same file as the certificate. **Google Cloud does not
> validate the certificate chain for you – validation is your responsibility.**

There is also information about the trust chain when you are creating a Certificate in GCP via UI, that your trust chain must be correct.

> The certificate must be in PEM format and **include correct certificate trust chain.** The certificate chain must be no greater than 5 certs long.

[image]

**Solution**

Solution to this issue was to merge the certificate chain with OP's certificate.

**Useful links**

- [Creating a .pem File for SSL Certificate Installations](https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm), especially part `Creating a .pem with the Private Key and Entire Trust Chain`
- [How to combine various certificates into single .pem](https://serverfault.com/questions/476576/how-to-combine-various-certificates-into-single-pem)

Comment: This definitely solves the problem, kudos to the whole explanation

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to upload the Public Key to the LoadBalancer. Only the certificate and Private Key are needed.

The Public key portion is embedded into the [Certificate](http://The%20Public%20key%20portion%20is%20embedded%20into%20the%20certificate%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate#Validation_levels)

Comment: But in youtube videos and blogs all are using public key certificate and also it is showing on google but not mine. If you are saying not required so why gtmetrix and other website ssl checker sites are showing certificate chain error.

Comment: Which videos or blogs show that you need a public key ?

Comment: Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qXM7kHlk1U at 2:25.

Comment: That odd indeed. I checked my console and i have similar fields to your's. Only certificate and private key are required.

What kind of error do you see in sslchecker?

Comment: I updated my question please check . Certificate chain is the main issue.

Comment: Aha so the certificate chain would be your .pem file

here is the doc you want to look at https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs

Comment: But when i am using certificate chain with private key then it is showing certificate and private key did not matched.

Comment: You can check that your private key and certificate match from the cli using these commands

openssl x509 –noout –modulus –in <file>.pem | openssl md5
openssl x509 –noout –modulus –in <file>.key | openssl md5

Replace file with the file name for your private key and certificate files. The output md5 should be the same. Otherwise your certificate and key doesn't match

Comment: My website is showing ssl but when I am checking on website speed sites showing certificate chain issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just **add main security certificate** at the **top of certificate chain** mostly contains **3 to 4 certificates** and add this **final certificate** in certificate field while creating a certificate. **then all things will be corrcted**. Thank you enjoy.